# Как правильно реализовать аудио-викторину?

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js

Будет вопрос в формате аудио, к нему будет 4 варианта ответа, один из которых верный.

1. Правильно ли хранить аудиозапись на хостинге, её название в БД?

Собираюсь сделать всё это делать, используя Nuxt Vue, PHP, MySQL.

2. Возможно ли использование иных средств разработки?

Я считаю, данные будут видны пользователю, если он решит покопаться в консоли.

Пример:

```
{
    question: "hello.mp3",
    correct: "Правильный ответ",
    options: "Вариант1, Вариант2, Вариант3"
}
```

Причём, по нажатии на кнопку «Следующий вопрос» будут приходить подобные данные.

3. Как можно скрыть эти данные?

P.S. Для добавления вопроса, нужна админка. Тут придётся "самописку" использовать?

Answer (score 2):

1. А где вы еще собрались хранить аудиозапись? Или использовать сторонний сервис?
2. Использование иных средств возможно, всё зависит от ваших предпочтений и задач
3. Данные с ответами пользователь видеть не должен, вы отправляете выбранный вариант на сервер и там его обрабатываете, возвращая в ответ результат

> P.S. Для добавления вопроса, нужна админка. Тут придётся "самописку" использовать?

Если вы знаете инструменты которые решают вашу задачу, то не пишите своё, если таких инструментов нет - пишите.